# Addthis javascript button/widget adding space to top of webpage

Tags: javascript, html

If you view this page http://www.herkimer.edu/news/view/community_members_complete_jointly_offered_machine_operator_training_progra/

You'll notice a green bar (screen-shot: http://grab.by/1msh) at the very top. It has something to do w/ the addthis widget you'll see underneath the h1 title.

If you reload the page a couple times, the bar goes away, probably because the script is cached and does not delay, resulting in that extra space at top.

Do you know what I could do to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you don't want the DIV to display.  You could add some CSS to the page to hide it.  It has id `atffc` (and contains a Flash object, but I don't know that it needs to be visible).

```
#atffc { display: none; }
```

Comment: I could not find the id atffc, where did you see it?

Comment: Firefox/firebug -- use inspect element and click on the "bar".  The DIV has the id atffc.

Comment: The swf in the div is used for analytics purposes, I believe. Hiding it did the trick for us since we don't use/care about tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I think in addition to just hiding your extra div you may want to move the  elements to the bottom of your page so they are evaluated after the add_this anchor tag () is created and ready.  That would help with potential timing issues to make sure the element is loaded and ready before their code starts to try to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I downloaded their new code 
http://www.addthis.com/web-button-select

I selected "no analytics" and I think they now strip out the flash part when using no analytics. I haven't had the problem again the last time I checked but I'll need more time to confirm this.

You might want to try to do the same

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but try adding this code AFTER the AddThis button code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = {
  data_use_flash: false
}
</script>
```

Source:
http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=22569&sid=fec603f0cac141b4856eddab92c8e63e&start=10