# Are your familiar with this code injected by firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

```
<div id="atffc">
    <object height="1px" width="1px" id="atff" data="//bin.clearspring.com/at/v/1/button1.6.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

It only happens the first time you visit.

And I checked there is no such code in source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953318/addthis-javascript-button-widget-adding-space-to-top-of-webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't add that, it'll be a script on the website you're visiting. [Clearspring](http://www.clearspring.com/) is:

> ... the leading provider of social distribution solutions connecting online publishers and advertisers to audiences on the social web. **Our free platform, AddThis, powers over 500K web properties, reaching 600 million users worldwide** – over half the Internet audience.
>
> Our technologies are used by the largest entertainment companies including NBC, Disney, Fox, MTV and Turner. Leading brands such as Sprint, Verizon, Clearasil, and Snickers leverage our paid performance-based distribution solutions to engage their audiences on Facebook, MySpace, and MyYearbook.

More information might be found on their [API Page](http://www.clearspring.com/docs/tech/apis/in-widget) or in [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=bin.clearspring.com).